# MongoDB Map-Reduce Find Values from Last Record per User

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to get some data about the authors of twitter posts, based on the latest data I have

Given a collection of twitter posts, I want to pull information from the latest post per author - ie. I want per author to get the friend count.

Roughly the collection has data like this.

> [{"post":
>   {"post_date":  "Sat, 24 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000" 
>       {"author": {"author_id":123, "friend_count":321}} 
>   ,{"post_date":  "Sat, 17 Mar 2012 03:22:11 +0000" 
>       {"author": {"author_id":123, "friend_count":311}} 
>   ,{"post_date":  "Sat, 10 Mar 2012 03:22:11 +0000" 
>       {"author": {"author_id":123, "friend_count":331}} }}]

I don't want the max of the friend_count but the value from the latest post.

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use mapreduce, you can do this with simple aggregation.

Something to the effect of:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
         {$sort:{post_date:-1}}, 
         {$group:{_id:"$author.author_id", friend_count:{$first:"$author.friend_count"}}}
)
```

Given the simplified sample data you gave this will `$sort` it by post_date newest to oldest, so that then when grouping by author_id, the `$first` record will be one that's the latest.

Comment: Asya is right. By the way, [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) was introduced from v2.2.

Comment: Thank you for the aggregation answer.  Does anyone know how this would look as map-reduce (for my education).

Comment: I do know how it would look - you might find it educational to go through the exercise of writing the map/reduce job (it'll make you appreciate aggregation framework so much more!)  :)

Comment: I do know how it would look - you might find it educational to go through the exercise of writing the map/reduce job (it'll make you appreciate aggregation framework so much more!)  :)