# Get latest document in collection for each user

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the latest document in a collection for each user in the collection. For example, lets assume I have data like this:

```js
[
    { user: "bob", time: ISODate("Sat, 24 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "a" },
    { user: "bob", time: ISODate("Sun, 25 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "b" },
    { user: "joe", time: ISODate("Sat, 24 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "c" },
    { user: "bob", time: ISODate("Mon, 26 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "d" },
    { user: "joe", time: ISODate("Sun, 25 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "e" }
]
```

After querying, I want to get back these entries:

```js
[
    { user: "bob", time: ISODate("Mon, 26 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "d" },
    { user: "joe", time: ISODate("Sun, 25 Mar 2012 05:52:21 +0000"), value: "e" }
]
```

I saw this question here: [MongoDB Map-Reduce Find Values from Last Record per User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907038/mongodb-map-reduce-find-values-from-last-record-per-user), but it doesn't quite seem to be the right answer I'm looking for. How do I query for this data?

Comment: Is that how your time is actually formatted or are you just stripping out the ISODate() part for formatting? If they are actually strings then you have problem

Comment: No, they are actually ISODate()s, I just wrote it that way for simplicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`$last`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operator with the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method to do this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "user": 1, "time": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$user",
        "time": { "$last": "$time" },
        "value": { "$last": "$value" }
    }}
])
```

So you are taking the **"last"** items from the grouping boundary to return the values. The use of `$last` really only makes sense after a sort in most cases, but for increasing inserts like this that stage can probably be excluded.

Probably worth noting that you could also use the `_id` value in place of a time-stamp to `$sort` on as it's value always increases as well.